# How to auto merge faces?

Tags: modeling

i apologize in advance because im sure my question isn't very clear.
Basically when I extend these faces out:[image]

i want this face:[image]

and this face:[image]

To be merged so it would look something like this:[image]

Except i did that manually is there a way to have that happen automatically? Also its probably important to mention that im new to blender, and not very good at explaining. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: When i say new to blender i mean you might have to explain more than usual.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any trick to do it, you can enable the snap option/ vertex mode, enable the Auto Merge option, extrude, let it snap, then delete the inner faces

Comment: How would i go about enabling auto merge?

Comment: on the top right of the 3D view > Options > Auto Merge

Answer (score 1):

Use **Extrude Manifold** tool (instead *Extrude*) just select front face and move forward with *Snap to Vertex* ...

[image]

... than move it up.

[image]

Since faces around becomes non-plannar and internally a triangulation happens in unexpected direction it is better to search for *Quads to Triangles* operator (that does tris in shorter distance) ...

[image]

... or you can use *Knife* tool to triangulate manually by longer edge.

[image]